# Selecting a column with multiple levels of column naming

Tags: python, pandas

How do I select a particular column from a DataFrame when there are multiple levels of naming?

```
>>>  x = pd.DataFrame({'instance':['first','first','first'],'foo':['a','b','c'],'bar':rand(3)})
>>> x = x.set_index(['instance','foo']).transpose()
>>> x.columns
MultiIndex
[(u'first', u'a'), (u'first', u'b'), (u'first', u'c')]
>>> x
instance     first                    
foo              a         b         c
bar       0.102885  0.937838  0.907467
```

*(Note: this question is asked in the comments to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21443963/pandas-multilevel-column-names#comment32357349_21443963) and there is an answer also in the comments. Thought it'd be good to have it as a question in its own right.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly the purpose of Multiindex slicers, see docs [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#multiindexing-using-slicers)

```
In [15]: idx = pd.IndexSlice

In [16]: x.loc[:,idx[:,'a']]
Out[16]: 
instance     first
foo              a
bar       0.525356

In [17]: x.loc[:,idx[:,['a','c']]]
Out[17]: 
instance     first          
foo              a         c
bar       0.525356  0.418152
```

Comment: Is there anyone in the world who can actually understand this? I've read the docs and they boggle my mind.

Comment: Also: is there a way to do this in `0.13.1`?

Comment: in older versions  you can use ``.xs`` (for a single label but on on any level/axis), or ``x.loc[:,x.columns.get_level_values(1).isin(['a','c])]`` for multiple