# Two columns with a common heading in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I need to display a table as shown in image. I am able to color the cells using pandas [style](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html). But, unable to club two columns with a common header the same way we do in Excel Spreadsheets with merge cells. Is there a way to do this in Pandas while displaying the data frame?

[image]

Comment: Check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21443963/pandas-multilevel-column-names

Comment: Check this one too, much more similar to your's : http://stackoverflow.com/a/27424102/1965509