# How to add multilevel column name to specific column only(not all the columns) in python pandas.DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index, multi-level

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40225683/how-to-simply-add-a-column-level-to-a-pandas-dataframe?answertab=active#tab-top) for the question background. I want to add `C` to only column `B`.

I need output as:

```
 df
    Out[92]: 
       A  B
          C
    a  0  0
    b  1  1
    c  2  2
    d  3  3
    e  4  4
```

I tried [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26332512/5320982) as :

```
dfnew=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[4,5,6]})

columns=[('c','b')]  #changed from columns=[('c','a'),('c','b')]

dfnew.columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(columns)
```

But that doesn't works. `ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 2 elements, new values have 1 elements`

Comment: If someone has better approach(like some manipulation to pd.MultiIndex) pls do post ! Will be accepted if better than accepted answer. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`MultiIndex.from_arrays`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays.html):

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.columns, ['','C']])

   A  B
      C
a  0  0
b  1  1
c  2  2
d  3  3
e  4  4
```

---

Note that [`pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples.html) is expecting a list of tuples, as the name suggests. If you check the source code, you'll see that if that is not the case, it will create one from the nested list by `zipping` it:

```
list(zip(*[df.columns, ['','C']]))
# [('A', ''), ('B', 'C')]
```

Which is the reason why you don't get what you expect.

---

If you want to do the same by specifying a list of columns, you could do:

```
cols = [(i, 'C') if i in ['B','D'] else (i, '') for i in df.columns]
# [('A', ''), ('B', 'C'), ('C', ''), ('D', 'C')]
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(cols)

   A  B  C  D
      C     C
a  0  0  0  0
b  1  1  1  1
c  2  2  2  2
d  3  3  3  3
e  4  4  4  4
```

Comment: Can we place for the nth column ? or by specific column name like in this case can we specify that `C`  should be placed under `B` only ? Because it would be quite troublesome if there are many columns before `B` which there are in my actual case !

Comment: Updating soon @Rex5

Comment: Check now @Rex5

Comment: that's good yet if you find some other method do update please! thanks !