# Add header under two columns of a table

Tags: python, pandas

I want to add another header under two columns of a table.

I tried this way but I got `InvalidSyntax`

```
table = {
        'Color':color,
        'Continent':continent,
        {'Country':country,
        'Nation':season,}
        'Name':name,
        'Surname':surname,
    }
```

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21443963/pandas-multilevel-column-names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use multiindex as described [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html). Given the structure you show in your dictionary this should do:

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('Color'),('Continent'),('Country','Nation'),('Country','Name'),('Country','Surname')])
```

For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Color':['Red','Green'],
                   'Continent':['Asia','Africa'],
                   'Nation':['China','Egypt'],
                   'Name':['X','Y'],
                   'Surname':['A','B']})
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(['Color']),(['Continent']),('Country','Nation'),('Country','Name'),('Country','Surname')])
print(df)
```

Outputs:

```
   Color    Continent  Country             
   NaN      NaN        Nation   Name    Surname
0  Red      Asia       China    X       A
1  Green    Africa     Egypt    Y       B
```